# Create a simple lock and key function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, locking

```py
class Lock:
 
   def __init__(self):
        self.key_code = "1234"  # Change this to your desired key code
        self.is_locked = True

    def lock(self):
        self.is_locked = True

    def unlock(self, entered_code):
        if entered_code == self.key_code:
            self.is_locked = False
        else:
            print("Incorrect key code. Lock remains locked.")

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.is_locked


def main():
    my_lock = Lock()

    print("The lock is currently locked.")
    while my_lock.is_locked():
        entered code = input("Enter the key code: ")
        my_lock.unlock(entered code)

    print("The lock is now unlocked.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I wrote this code but it is showing an

```py
Type Error: 'bool' object is not callable
The lock is currently locked.
```

I have been trying to create a lock mechanism but it is showing an type error. I had tried many ways but I still couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to do it.

```py
class Lock:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key_code = "1234"  # Change this to your desired key code
        self.is_locked = True

    def lock(self):
        self.is_locked = True

    def unlock(self, entered_code):
        if entered_code == self.key_code:
            self.is_locked = False
        else:
            print("Incorrect key code. Lock remains locked.")

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.is_locked


def main():
    my_lock = Lock()

    print("The lock is currently locked.")
    while my_lock.is_locked:  # <-- Use variable here instead of getter
        entered_code = input("Enter the key code: ")
        my_lock.unlock(entered_code)

    print("The lock is now unlocked.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works but you want to use a getter to access your variable.

```py
class Lock:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key_code = "1234"  # Change this to your desired key code
        self.locked = True

    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True

    def unlock(self, entered_code):
        if entered_code == self.key_code:
            self.locked = False
        else:
            print("Incorrect key code. Lock remains locked.")

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.locked


def main():
    my_lock = Lock()

    print("The lock is currently locked.")
    while my_lock.is_locked():
        entered_code = input("Enter the key code: ")
        my_lock.unlock(entered_code)

    print("The lock is now unlocked.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem was that a variable and method have the same name. The hint was in the error - it was using the variable thinking it to be a method instead of using a method with the same name. Changing the variable to `locked` made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there: there is slight mistake in your code
i. The constructor method should be named **init** (with double underscores) instead of init.
ii. You had both an instance variable named is_locked and a method named is_locked. This can cause conflicts. I renamed the method to is_locked_status to avoid the conflict.
iii. When calling the is_locked_status method, you need to use parentheses () to invoke the method and get its return value.

```
class Lock:
    def __init__(self):  # Use double underscores for the constructor method name
        self.key_code = "1234"
        self.is_locked = True

    def lock(self):
        self.is_locked = True

    def unlock(self, entered_code):
        if entered_code == self.key_code:
            self.is_locked = False
        else:
            print("Incorrect key code. Lock remains locked.")

    def is_locked_status(self):  # Rename the method to avoid name conflict
        return self.is_locked

def main():
    my_lock = Lock()

    print("The lock is currently locked.")
    while my_lock.is_locked_status():  # Call the renamed method
        entered_code = input("Enter the key code: ")
        my_lock.unlock(entered_code)
    print("The lock is now unlocked.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `is_locked` would better be used as the name of the predicate method. Since no one should be accessing the instance attribute directly (i.e., setting `my_lock.is_locked = False` without using the `unlock` method), the instance attribute would be better named `_is_locked` (or really, just `_locked`).